# How to get second of minute from epoch in java 8

Tags: java

I have epoch second from `Instant` in java 8.

```
   long epoch = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
```

How i get `second of minute` from it. like `1 to 60`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you want to achieve here, can you please provide an example? you already have Seconds so what exactly you want to do after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for example via the `ZoneDateTime` class

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
System.out.println(zdt.getSecond() + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably something like this as direct approach:

```
Instant.now().getEpochSecond() % 60 + 1;
```

Comment: @Fleshgrinder In the question is specified seconds from 1 to 60, that's the reason of the + 1.

Comment: You are right, in that case, the accepted answer is wrong as it provides 0..60.